# While trying to read the content of the file in S3 bucket using java getting access denied

Tags: amazon-s3

While i am trying to read content of file in S3 bucket using java i am getting error like this

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 
AccessDenied; Request ID:XXXXXXX)is there any issue in my permissions or
roles please kindly advise.
```

regards,
JJ

Comment: how anyone would help you if don't mention what permissions are you using or post your code

Comment: Here's the same question,Maybe it can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798926/com-amazonaws-services-s3-model-amazons3exception-access-denied